# Angular form data / model data duplication

Tags: forms, angularjs, scope

Starting out with angular, Ive developed an app which builds a form with directives dynamically chosen from the field type in the data from the server. All the fields are bound to data within $scope using ng-model. The data is loaded and saved to the server using $http.

Today I've looked at Angular forms, and by wrapping all this in a form element, and giving names to each input, I automatically have validation etc, which is very nice.

But now I notice there are two sets of data maintained - my bound data from my model in $scope, and the data separately maintained by the Angular form directive.

Looking at the Angular docs for eg form or input, the example also binds to $scope (ng-model="text"), but form data is separate (myForm.input.*).

Is this apparent duplication best practice? Or is there a way to unify my model with the data maintained by the Angular form, under one structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form and `ng-model` (using `ngmodelcontroller`) directives provide a mechanism to support form validation and 2 way data binding  on `input` elements.

What the form provides as data is current state of the form and its element, which beyond the standard `model` that you bind using `ng-model`. Duplication of code is bad, but here data in the form is being tracked by the form directive so it is fine.